# TypeError: target.roles.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a userinfo command, however, under the Roles bit, it errors saying:
`TypeError: target.roles.map is not a function`

**Expected result:**

```js
console.log(target.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(" ,"))
```

It will log out the roles that they have in the specific server.

**Actual result:**

```js
console.log(target.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(" ,")
```

It will log: `TypeError: target.roles.map is not a function`

**What have I tried?**

I tried doing:

```js
console.log(target.roles.cache.map(r => `${r}`).join(" ,"))
```

Still logged the same thing but it has cache before the `.map`.

Code:

```js
const {Client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')
const moment = require('moment')

module.exports = {
    name: 'userinfo',
    description: "show the info type",
    type: 'CHAT_INPUT',
    options: [
        {
            name: 'target',
            description: 'target to get info on',
            type: 'USER',
            required: false
        }
    ],
    default_permission: true,
/**
 * 
 * @param {Client} client 
 * @param {CommandInteraction} int 
 * @param {String[]} args 
 */
    run: async(client, int, args) => {
        const target = int.options.getMember('target') || int.member

        let status;
        let statusEmoji
        switch (target.presence.status) {
            case "online":
                status = 'Online'
                statusEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get(`960628219608985650`)
                break;
            case "idle":
                status = 'Idle'
                statusEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get(`960628219621572638`)
                break;
            case "dnd":
                status = 'Do not Disturb'
                statusEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get(`960628123806879744`)
                break;
            case "offline":
                status = 'Offline'
                statusEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get(`960628219550249071`)
                break;
        }     

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('YELLOW')
        .setTitle(`${target.user.tag}'s Info`)
        .setThumbnail(target.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .addFields(
            {
                name: ':bust_in_silhouette: | Username:',
                value: `${target.user.username}`,
                inline: false
            },
            {
                name: ':busts_in_silhouette: | Nickname (Guild Username):',
                value: target.nickname ? `${target.nickname}` : `Same as discord username!`,
                inline: false
            },
            {
                name: ':hash: | Discriminator:',
                value: `${target.user.discriminator}`,
                inline: false
            },

            {
                name: ':id: | User ID:',
                value: `${target.user.id}`,
                inline: false
            },

            {
                name: `${client.emojis.cache.get('960628123806879744')} | Current Status:`,
                value: `${statusEmoji} | ${status}`,
                inline: false
            },

            {
                name: `:video_game: | Activity:`,
                value: target.presence.activities ? target.presence.activities[1].name : "This user isn't on activity!",
                inline: false
            },
            {
                name: `:new: | Registered at:`,
                value: moment.utc(target.user.createdAt).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss'),
                inline: false
            },
            {
                name: `:speech_balloon: | Joined at:`,
                value: moment.utc(target.joinedAt).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss'),
                inline: false
            },
            {
                name: `Roles:`,
                value: target.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(" ,"),
                inline: false
            }
        )
        .setTimestamp()

        int.followUp({ embeds: [ embed ] })
    }
}
```

Comment: So that means `target.roles` is not an array f it does not have map. `console.log(target.roles);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

This is now solved by me.

**How?**

Firstly, I have been testing. The code I did was the `filter`, without the `.join` and `.name`, it logs all the information with my role. However when I add on `.name` and `.join`, it will error.

Secondly, I tried using the `.cache.map` method again but with the '``' and `${}` way, it logged the roles that I had. I added on the `.join(", ")` after the `.map(...)`.